# Powershell: Perform an operation on all files in a directory (foreach)

Tags: powershell

In bash, the equivalent would be

```
for x in `ls *.zip` do ; unzip $x ; done
```

How do I do this in Windows Powershell.

**Update** As Johannes Rössel pointed out this is a bad example (unzip *.zip) but what I'm after is the "foreachness" of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ls *.zip | foreach-object { unzip $_ }
```

Comment: Unfortunate example: `unzip *.zip` easily works.

Comment: Canonical powershell uses `gci` or `Get-ChildItem`.